# Merge a differential pair into one signal

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga

I have an [LVDS ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads6143.pdf) connecting to an Altera Cyclone IV FPGA. The data pins come in 7 differential pair channels, for a total of 14 pins.

Although each differential pair is physically 2 pins, my Verilog code expects only one signal for each pair.

How should I tell the FPGA that each differential pair should be merged into one signal for my Verilog code? Is this done in Verilog? Is this done in the contraints file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cyclone FPGA has differential line receivers built-in, and you use those by instantiating them in your design. My usual approach is to create a separate module that represents the "pad ring" for the chip, and instantiate them there.
You'll have two external pins for each logical signal used in the interior.

Answer (score 4):

Altera FPGAs can easily interface LVDS signals. Assign a signal to a pin in Pin Planner, then select that pin type as LVDS and a complementary pair will be generated automatically. Plus it will also assign a negative pin when You select location of positive pin and vice versa.